# panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference || r.body model

Tags: go

I have problem newbie Go Programming like: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Sometime I can resolve the problem, but this is make me confuse.
this is the code in Handler level, I tried to implement ###p.repo.UpdateProfile()
and data from r.body decode

```
//UpdateProfile handler
func (p *Profile) UpdateProfile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var (
        errForm   models.ErrorForm
        resp      models.Response
        respError models.ErrorResponse
        errField  models.ErrField
        data      *models.EditProfile
    )

    userid := r.Context().Value(viper.GetString("token.userid"))
        
        errDecode := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)

    errPayload := p.repo.UpdateProfile(r.Context(), data, userid)

    if errPayload.Error() == "username_exist" {
        respError.Message = "username already taken"
        respError.Status = 422
        lib.ResJSON(w, respError.Status, respError)
        return
    }
    lib.Catch(errPayload)

    resp.Data = ""
    resp.Message = "Success"
    resp.Status = 200

    lib.ResJSON(w, resp.Status, resp)
}
```

### and the Method like:

```
func (m *mysqlProfileRepo) UpdateProfile(ctx context.Context, p *models.EditProfile, userid interface{}) error {
    query := ""
    var checkexist int

    row1, err1 := m.Conn.QueryContext(ctx, query, p.Username)
    if err1 != nil {
        return err1
    }

    for row1.Next() {
        if errSc1 := row1.Scan(&checkexist); errSc1 != nil {
            return errors.New("error_scan_db")
        }
    }

    if checkexist != 0 {
        return errors.New("username_exist")
    }

    query1 := ""
    query2 := ""

    stmts := []*lib.PipelineStmt{
        lib.NewPipelineStmt(query1, p.Image, p.Location, p.Link, p.Bio, p.Birthday, userid),
        lib.NewPipelineStmt(query2, p.Username, p.Fullname, userid),
    }

    errTrx := lib.WithTransaction(m.Conn, func(tx lib.Transaction) error {
        _, errRunPipe := lib.RunPipeline(tx, stmts...)
        return errRunPipe
    })

    if errTrx != nil {
        return errTrx
    }

    return nil
}
```

#### MyCode work well in database, the data successfully updated, but the response server is

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2019/07/21 13:27:36 goroutine 8 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0xc00028e100, 0x16b1a20, 0xc000094040)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9d
github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware.Recoverer.func1.1(0xc00028e100, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware/recoverer.go:25 +0x9c
panic(0x155e7a0, 0x1a66a10)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
audioo_api/handler.(*Profile).UpdateProfile(0xc000020030, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e200)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/audioo_api/handler/profile.go:73 +0x524
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000020050, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e200)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
audioo_api/lib/mid.Authenticate.func1.1(0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/audioo_api/lib/mid/auth.go:48 +0x71e
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e0a0, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*ChainHandler).ServeHTTP(0xc000066140, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/chain.go:31 +0x52
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).routeHTTP(0xc0000a5f80, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:425 +0x27f
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000020040, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).ServeHTTP(0xc0000a5f80, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:70 +0x451
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).Mount.func1(0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:292 +0x127
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e0e0, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).routeHTTP(0xc0000a59e0, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:425 +0x27f
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc0001db880, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).ServeHTTP(0xc0000a59e0, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:70 +0x451
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).Mount.func1(0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:292 +0x127
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e180, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).routeHTTP(0xc0000a5920, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:425 +0x27f
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000020090, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
audioo_api/lib/mid.Limit.func1(0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/audioo_api/lib/mid/limit.go:79 +0xe5
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e1a0, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/cors.(*Cors).Handler.func1(0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/cors/cors.go:201 +0x1a4
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e1c0, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware.Recoverer.func1(0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware/recoverer.go:35 +0x9f
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e1e0, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware.RedirectSlashes.func1(0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware/strip.go:53 +0x202
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e200, 0x16b6be0, 0xc000256280, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware.(*Compressor).Handler.func1.1(0x1f69180, 0xc000256240, 0xc00028e100)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware/compress.go:190 +0x254
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00000e2c0, 0x1f69180, 0xc000256240, 0xc00028e100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware.RequestLogger.func1.1(0x16b78a0, 0xc000226000, 0xc00028e000)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware/logger.go:46 +0x291
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00009a210, 0x16b78a0, 0xc000226000, 0xc00028e000)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).ServeHTTP(0xc0000a5920, 0x16b78a0, 0xc000226000, 0xc000154000)
    /Users/rizaldinurmuhammad/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:82 +0x294
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc00009c410, 0x16b78a0, 0xc000226000, 0xc000154000)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2774 +0xa8
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002ce640, 0x16b8aa0, 0xc000067340)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1878 +0x851
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.6/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2884 +0x2f4
```

#### I have tried to change context to implement database but the response still the same.

I wonder this problem related in r.body, but I dont know how to figure out

Comment: What are you doing with errDecode from. 
             
     `errDecode := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)` ?

Comment: Define error if decode fail, I am not give all the code, I have handle this errDecode

Comment: The code you left out may be important.
`data` is already a pointer. what is the line at audioo_api/handler/profile.go:73 and what post request middleware you have?

Comment: in line 73, I call method p.repo.Updateprofile(). in this method, the "data" appear if I fmt.println(data) same as input in body request. You can see I block if username already exist, so far in this line code the server work well the response "Username already exist", but if passed the the server responses invali address BUT the data successfull updated in my DB. OMG :(

Comment: I tried to not use middleware authorized but, still the error still the same

Comment: the root problem you can see at your question , at `audioo_api/handler/profile.go:73` this one make it panic
and the what make panic we need figure out the code at thoose line,
but for the learning you must check if the data type is pointer better you check first is nil or not, if you just pass, it could be something happen to panic if you access the value inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the package documentation for Body io.ReadCloser:

> For client requests, a nil body means the request has no body, such as a GET request. For server requests, the Request Body is always non-nil.

You say, it's a server, so, it's always non-nil, thus the error is in the `Decode` call where you pass a pointer to the nil pointer.

`data` is a `nil` pointer, `&data` is a pointer to a `nil` pointer.

Solution if data is a non interface type, unless `models` package explicitly forbids `new(EditProfile)`:

```
    data = new(models.EditProfile)
    errDecode := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(data)
```

If data is an interface, allocate a real value for it first, and again pass without a reference to `Decode`: `errDecode := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(data)`

And in the latter case also double check if you declare the right type `*models.EditProfile`.

Comment: if I change data = new(models.EditProfile), the "data" from r.body not carried away. and this error still appear

Comment: Have you changed the `Decode` part as well, I mean, have you removed the reference? 

And if yes, then there's something wrong with the caller of your `Profile.UpdateProfile` method, check why it receives the `Request` with `nil` `Body` field.

Can you give a bit more details on the setup, specifically, what is the source of the `Request`, do you have control over that code, and if so, can you specify the line where the `Request` value is created and how, when it is being used to call `Profile.UpdateProfile` method?